# Namespace issue with wsdl generated from JAX WS

Tags: soap, jaxb, wsdl, jax-ws

I have a web service deployed on tomcat server and also have generated a wsdl file for the same.

Later I generated a new soap project through wsdl, and executed a soap request to the server.

The problem here is at the server side, unmarshalling of xml is failing because of namespace prefix for "InputData" and "CCNA" are wrong. Currently it is **cfa**.

According to java code, The namespaces for InputData is **xs** and CCNA is **bim**. 
So, if I modify the soap request, unmarshall is fine on server side.

So, where is the issue ? WSDL generation or anywhere else in JAX WS ?
I should not be modifying my soap request.

**SOAP request :**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cfa="http://cfa.ni.ctl.com/" xmlns:bim="http://www.qwest.com/XMLSchema/BIM" xmlns:xs="http://www.qwest.com/XMLSchema">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cfa:getCFACircuit>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <CFACircuitRequest>
            <bim:RequestId>123</bim:RequestId>
            <bim:WebServiceName>123</bim:WebServiceName>
            <bim:RequestPurpose>123</bim:RequestPurpose>
            <bim:AuthorizationInfo>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <bim:ApplicationId>123</bim:ApplicationId>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <bim:UserId>123</bim:UserId>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <bim:Userid>123</bim:Userid>
               <bim:Password>123</bim:Password>
            </bim:AuthorizationInfo>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <bim:TargetSchemaVersionUsed>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <bim:TargetXSDName>123</bim:TargetXSDName>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <bim:MajorVersionNumber>123</bim:MajorVersionNumber>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <bim:MinorVersionNumber>123</bim:MinorVersionNumber>
            </bim:TargetSchemaVersionUsed>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <bim:TimeOutSecond>123</bim:TimeOutSecond>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <bim:SendTimeStamp>123</bim:SendTimeStamp>
            <cfa:InputData>
               <cfa:CCNA>123</cfa:CCNA>
               <xs:CableKey>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <xs:LowUnit>123</xs:LowUnit>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <xs:HighUnit>123</xs:HighUnit>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <xs:CableId>123</xs:CableId>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <xs:CableSubPath>123</xs:CableSubPath>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <xs:CLLIALocation>123</xs:CLLIALocation>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <xs:CLLIZLocation>123</xs:CLLIZLocation>
               </xs:CableKey>
            </cfa:InputData>
         </CFACircuitRequest>
      </cfa:getCFACircuit>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

XML annotation for Input data on server is  :

@XmlElement(name = "InputData", namespace = "http://www.qwest.com/XMLSchema", required = true)

Comment: I don't know why with this annotation the inputData in the wsdl it isn't in the corresponding namespaces... maybe an issue related with jaxb version? can you try with a newer one? Sorry but I don't know how to help here. I will also remove my answer since it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: ok..thanks..I try with a newer jaxb version

Answer (score 0):

I would guess your XML request is incorrect. Please try to validate first your request against XML schema.

It does not matter which namespace prefix you use, but you need to make sure the XML elements match to the appropriate namespace.

Comment: <cfa:InputData>
               <cfa:CCNA>123</cfa:CCNA>

Answer (score 0):

Ajay,
your annotation is:

@XmlElement(name = "InputData", namespace = "http://www.qwest.com/XMLSchema", required = true)

But in your XML request the element InputData belongs to the namespace "http://cfa.ni.ctl.com/".

You need to fix the annotation.

Comment: But that code is auto generated from schema file..I include the jar file in my server package.. how do I override the namespace in my code ?